# EXT4 filesystem Superblock invalid after lvextend and power failure

Tags: linux, lvm, ext4, superblock

There was a LVM with VG on two partition-based PVs

My bad, everything following was happening on a mounted filesystem.

I've successfully added third PV

```
pvcreate /dev/sdc2
```

Successfully extended the VG

```
vgextend vgstorage /dev/sdc2
```

Successfully extended the LV

```
lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/vgstorage/lvstorage
```

There was a power failure one or two hours after extension and after that the filesystem is currepted.

```
dmesg | grep dm-4
[    7.705752] EXT4-fs (dm-4): VFS: Found ext4 filesystem with invalid superblock checksum.  Run e2fsck?
```

I tried:

```
e2fsck /dev/dm-4
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
ext2fs_open2: Superblock checksum does not match superblock
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Superblock checksum does not match superblock while trying to open /dev/dm-4

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Suggested superblocks here didn't work either.

Testdisk under >[ Advanced ] Filesystem Utils the >[Superblock] displays the following:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/vgstorage-lvstorage - 35 TB / 32 TiB - 70219857920 sectors

     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

  ext4                           0 70219857919 70219857920
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 []
  ext4                      262144 70220120063 70219857920
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 []
  ext4                      786432 70220644351 70219857920
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 []
  ext4                     1310720 70221168639 70219857920
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 []
  ext4                     1835008 70221692927 70219857920
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 []
  ext4                     2359296 70222217215 70219857920
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 []
  ext4                     6553600 70226411519 70219857920
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 []
  ext4                     7077888 70226935807 70219857920
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 []
  ext4                    12845056 70232702975 70219857920
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 []
  ext4                    21233664 70241091583 70219857920
superblock 0, blocksize=4096 []

To repair the filesystem using alternate superblock, run
fsck.ext4 -p -b superblock -B blocksize device
enter code here
```